# How to set custom font for a listview in adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter, custom-font

I have a listview layout set for an adapter. I want to set custom-font for this particular adapter, how can i do. Can i use below two lines and do it ?

```
Typeface customfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/omnesreg.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(customfont);
```

Comment: @maven : Thanks, i have tried doing same. But now i get nothing in list view its empty. Can you check. I have edited code in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Holder can help you here**

Create your own custom adapter and set font for the text.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ViewHolder will buffer the assess to the individual fields of the row
    // layout

    ViewHolder holder;
    // Recycle existing view if passed as parameter
    // This will save memory and time on Android
    // This only works if the base layout for all classes are the same
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_listview, null, true);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.main_name);
        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    Typeface customfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/omnesreg.ttf");
    holder.textView.setTypeface(customfont);
    holder.textView.setText(title);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: What if the fonts need to be pulled from an array? What if each font has a different custom typeface?             ``textViewArray[i] = new TextView(getContext());
            for( int j = 0; j <= fonts.length - 1; j++) {
                textViewArray[i].setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/" + fonts[j] + ".ttf"));
            }`` I guess you could use something like that but then how would it communicate with the main activity?

Comment: @ bluemunch how many textview font styles you have and howmany items in your list?? Do you want even or odd position of list item font change ??